# Admin page button create new

Tags: plugins

I have made a plugin and now i want to include a button into my plugin, see image.

How can i achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just HTML code. Follow this structure.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>
        PAGE TITLE GOES HERE 
        <a href="" class="page-title-action">
            BUTTON TEXT GOES HERE
        </a>
    </h1>
```